# Laravel 8.x to 9.x upgrade requirements issue

Tags: laravel-9

How can I fix?

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> - illuminate/database[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - illuminate/database[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - illuminate/database[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-permission ^4.2 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-permission[4.2.0, ..., v4.x-dev].
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.2 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.3 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.4 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.5 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.3.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.3.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - spatie/laravel-permission[4.2.0, ..., v4.x-dev] require illuminate/database ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by
>   illuminate/database[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7. 0.0, ..., 7.x-dev,
>   v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
> - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/database[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev], laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1 , ..., 9.x-dev]. laravel/framework
>   replaces illuminate/database and thus cannot coexist with it.
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev].

Comment: Remove vendor folder and copy the composer.json that i have posted and then run 'composer update' .

Comment: @Vipertecpro thanks man, this method worked for me. I was stuck with a stupid error from package facade/ignition that wouldn't let me upgrade from 8x to 9x and didn't nkow which package was causing it. I reoved vendor folder, backed up my old composer.json, copy-paster composer.json from the original 9x repo, ran composer update. It then would give me an error requiring some of the old pacages, which I added one by one in composer json until it didn't give any more errors and finished successfully. Then I added some other custom packages that were on the old composer.json.

Comment: @Altin That's Great news man,  Keep it up and please do upvote if solution worked for you, and keep posted more questions, after all we all are in this together. :D "Dev Tip : Never leave single file backed up." We can push other libraries to upgrade too because we are upgrading with time ( i mean with framwork stable release version ) and stability.

Answer (score 3):

Take backup of your old `composer.json`, just to refer for all the other packages that you are going to need.

Remove vendor folder and copy `composer.json` from below.

This is my fresh laravel 9 `composer.json` file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.2",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Then run `composer update`
After that if you want your old packages back then install one by one like this

`composer require spatie/laravel-permission`